# Oracle - hh mm ss to hh:mm:ss with one exotic

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an Oracel DB which contains two columns that have the format hhmmss. So 221000 stands for 22:10:00.

I want to make it to a right time format. The problem is that there is the value 240000, which is should be changed to 235959. Furthermore, leading zeros are omitted.

Does one know how to do this?

Greeting

Comment: Shouldn't 240000 be 000000 the following day?

Comment: Are you sure? I assume `240000` would rather mean `00:00:00`.

Comment: The date datatype in oracle would expect a "date" as well. so just time component wouldnt be appropriate. What is the date to be used for these time components

Comment: What's the datatype ofthose columns, string or numeric?

Comment: The objective is, to get the difference between to times. Its the start and end time. If the end time is 00:00:00 and the stat time 23:00:00, I would get a difference of -23:00:00 right? But it should be 1 hour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
select replace(to_char(t, '00,00,00'), ',', ':')
```

This doesn't handle the 24:00:00, but that seems like a valid time.  You can handle that using `case`:

```
select (case when t = 240000 then '23:59:59'  -- I would use '00:00:00'
             else replace(to_char(t, '00,00,00'), ',', ':')
        end)
```

Comment: The objective is, to get the difference between to times. Its the start and end time. If the end time is 00:00:00 and the stat time 23:00:00, I would get a difference of -23:00:00 right? But it should be 1 hour.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `case` expression to handle this usecase explicitly. For the others, you can convert this string to a date, and then format the date as you will:

```
SELECT CASE col
       WHEN '240000' THEN '23:59:59'
       ELSE TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(LPAD(col, 6, '0'), 'hh24miss'), 'hh24:mi:ss')
       ENDi
FROM   mytable
```

Comment: Using `TO_CHAR()` is just a revert back of what is actually requested.

Comment: I think your LTRIM should be an LPAD?

Comment: @CaiusJard yes, thanks. I misread the question and understood that OP wanted the leading zeroes removed, but on a second reading it's clear that this is not what he meant. Thanks for drawing attention to this.

Comment: And `mm` means *month*, should be `mi` instead

Answer (score 0):

Assumptions:

- Your table has a VARCHAR column holding the date in yyyymmdd
- Your table has a VARCHAR or INT column holding a time in hh24miss

What you really ought to do:

```
ALTER TABLE ADD proper_date DATETIME;
UPDATE table SET proper_date = TO_DATE(datecol || LPAD(timecol, 6, '0'), 'yyyymmddhh24miss');
```

If your table has a datetime holding the date, and an int or varchar holding the time:

```
UPDATE table SET the_date = TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(datecol, 'yyyymmdd') || LPAD(timecol, 6, '0'), 'yyyymmddhh24miss');
```

Then drop the separated columns- always a terrible idea in the face of a datatype designed for holding these things

Answer (score 0):

The simplest is probably to just convert the Hours separately from the minutes and seconds like so:

```
to_date(substr(t,-4),'miss') + to_number(substr(t,1,length(t)-4))/24
```

A key fact to note about this is that for hours >= 24 the resulting date will be a day or more later than those times with fewer hours, so subtracting the converted values 230000 from 240000 will result in a one hour difference as required.

Comment: Thanks, but there is no date/ day, I have just the HHMMSS values.

Comment: Yes, however, once it's been converted to a DATE data type with the TO_DATE function, the 1st of the current month is assumed for the date part, and the time part of the date data type comes from your data.  You can the use regular date arithmetic to subtract your start time from the end time to get the desired results. Just give it a try and see for yourself.